# Php page can't recognize "ø" from mysql value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field, $name (varchar(128)) in which there's a value "Pølse Mand".

Now I want it to print something special whenever the value is "Pølse Mand"

```
<?php 

if ($name=="Pølse Mand") { echo "123";};


?>
```

But for some reason this doesn't work. I also have another value named "Text box" and it works fine when I do the same with that, so it must be the "ø" that messes things up.

I assume my "ø" in the php file is somehow different from the ø in the value, even though I've tried copying it directly letter for letter in phpmyadmin.

The MySQL connection collation is utf8_unicode_ci and the collation in the table is latin1_swedish_ci. I have tried: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8_unicode_ci"/>` and with the swedish one, but it just doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried Polse Mand? The meta tag will not influence php in any way.

Comment: Have you verified the value of $name?

Comment: Jrod: Yes, it's been confirmed. echo $name prints out "Pølse Mand"

Comment: Stack 101: Yes, Polse Mand works fine.

Comment: I believe 'utf8_encode_ci" is the MySQL way of setting character sets. Does it work if you try this in your PHP file <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />. Also make sure that your editor saves your PHP files in utf-8, and not something else.

Answer (score 2):

You're using UTF-8 on the client side so must tell MySQL that you use UTF-8. This is done by the MySQL command SET NAMES 'utf8' which must be send as the first query on opening a connection. Depending on your installation and on the MySQL client library you use in the PHP script this can be done automatically on each connect.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "db");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

//

```
$mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using *MySql* or *MySqli*?

For MySQL use this code before the request:

```
mysql_set_charset ( 'latin7' );
```

or:

```
mysql_set_charset ( 'utf8' );
```

And for MySQLi:

```
$mysqli -> set_charset ( 'latin7' ); //Change $mysqli to your variable name
```

or:

```
$mysqli -> set_charset ( 'utf8' );
```

As for the `<meta>` tag, use:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

or:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-13"/>
```

Try both options and find which works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

try to change table encoding to utf8 and after mysql connection run query: `set names utf8`