# Why some special characters like Ð and D has same identity in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

When i delete from table where name like Ð
it removes all those items as well which contain D.
Same case with many special characters, how to resolve this issue in mysql with php.

Comment: I've just tried with table collation set to utf8_general_ci and it works perfectly fine. Make sure you use UTF-8 everywhere - MySql, connection function and PHP file itself (must be saved as UTF-8 without a BOM).

Comment: i have made utf8_general_ci, and i insert two values Ð and D, when i do delete from keywords where keyword='D' then Ð also deleted.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your collation, for instance:

```
mysql> SELECT 'é'= 'e' COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
+-----------------------------------+
| 'é'= 'e' COLLATE utf8_general_ci |
+-----------------------------------+
|                                 1 |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'é'= 'e' COLLATE utf8_bin;;
+----------------------------+
| 'é'= 'e' COLLATE utf8_bin |
+----------------------------+
|                          0 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can set it per connection if you like:

```
mysql> SET collation_connection=utf8_bin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'é'= 'e';
+-----------+
| 'é'= 'e' |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'é'= 'e';
+-----------+
| 'é'= 'e' |
+-----------+
|         1 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What character set are you actually using then (show a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statement, and the output of `show variables like '%char%';` & `show variables like '%collation%';`?

Comment: @Benjamin: yes, almost a direct quote from the answer. What are you trying to say with your remark?

Comment: lol, sorry I just noticed that I should've read your answer from top to bottom. Fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Change your column collation to `utf8_bin`.

Note that this will consider `D` and `d` different, as well.

Comment: does not work, i am using phpmyadmin and changing settings, but does not work

Comment: Are you sure you did change the collation? Try to do it manually, something like `ALTER TABLE table CHANGE column column VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

Similar question here :

[Php page can't recognize "ø" from mysql value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257668/php-page-cant-recognize-o-from-mysql-value/6257836#6257836)

```
$mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```